# Constrain a type to F# records?

Tags: f#, record

I'm trying to write a generic database storage function that appends a field to a record before saving it. Here's the general idea:

```ml
let storeItem item =
    let itemType = item.GetType().Name
    let storageItem = {| item with ItemType = itemType |}
    do db.StoreItem storageItem
```

Unfortunately, this will not compile due to the following error:

> FS3245: The input to a copy-and-update expression that creates an anonymous record must be either an anonymous record or a record

I can't find a way to constrain the type of `item` to be a record. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Even if you could restrict a type argument to be a record, you would not be able to do anything legitimately with it since records satisfy no common interface that you could do anything with.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie, It seems like there would be a lot of use cases that involve anonymous records around IO activities like databases and HTTP endpoints.

Comment: I wonder if I could use reflection to build a record on the fly. That seems overkill, but this is isolated code.

Comment: We are dealing with opposite ends of the spectrum here - F# with it's beautiful type system and reflection which allows you to break any type system. F# should never have allowed reflection - the type system is all about constraints, so it shouldn't have allowed people to escape them via reflection.